# Show and open bootstrap modals

Tags: javascript, jquery, typescript

I need to close one modal and show another modal in Angular5 web application. I'm using bootstrap components with Jquery.

```
$('#myModal').modal('show');
$('#myModal1').modal('hide');
```

I'm facing an error `Property 'modal' does not exist on type 'JQuery<HTMLElement>'`

Comment: Better to use ng-bootstrap or ngx-bootstrap for bootstrap 3 and 4.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [ng-bootstrap](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components) which make thing much easier

It's really easy to use.

Inject NgbModal and use .open method to open a modal with a certain component

```
import { SecondComponent} from 'second.component';
import { FirstComponent} from 'first.component';

import { NgbModal } from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';

export class AppComponent {
  constructor(public modalService: NgbModal) {}

  openFirstModal(){
    this.modalService.open(First)
  }

  openSecondModal(){
    // You can also get a reference to the component
    let ref = this.modalService.open(SecondComponent)
    ref.componentInstance.variable = "foo";
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to install `npm install -D @types/bootstrap` for the new version and you also need to make sure that your webpack configurations are correct if you are using webpack.